# How to read programmatically the DOM generated by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, plugins, code-inspection

I can inspect any Javascript-generated DOM by using Firebug or another debugger. Firebug also allows me to interactively copy the generated innerHTML of any element onto the Clipboard such that I can save it to the disk.

Is there a system/tool that allows to perform these interactive tasks programmatically? Such a tool/plugin should be able to read the Javascript-generated DOM and save it to the disk programmatically.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such tool will programmatically do that

Comment: What language do you prefer ? Or do you need an application ?

Comment: What is your goal? Debugging your JS or seeing what the JS in someone else's page does?

Comment: Are you targeting a particular browser?

Comment: @tryme: Please suggest anything.

Comment: I can use any browser. It could be sometimes interesting see DOMs of other people. But first of all I would like to know what other people can see and handle programmatically from my own page.

Comment: @Jiri http://www.fiddler2.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any existing tool that would allow you to do this, so you probably need to write your own script to solve this task.

You can certainly use a library like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to achieve this. Using it, you can even choose which browser you want to use to render the website.

If you are running on Linux, I can also recommend my own project [webkit-scraping](https://github.com/niklasb/webkit-scraping) for this (this recommendation is a bit biased, of course ;). It uses an in-memory Webkit instance to render the page and execute the Javascript in it. After compiling the server with `cd webkit-server && qmake && make`, you can do something like this in Python:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/webkit-scraping/lib')
import webkit_scraping

URL = 'http://example.org'
OUTFILE = '/tmp/example.html'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # set up a web scraping session
  driver = webkit_scraping.webkit_server.Driver()
  sess = webkit_scraping.scraping.Session(driver = driver)
  sess.visit(URL)

  with open(OUTFILE, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(sess.body())
```